# How to show Android app name on ActionBar of each Activity?

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-resources

I'm working right now on my first great app! Where **tm-s** is, I want to have **Hello world** for each `Activity`. Is it possible?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following

```
android:label="@string/app_name"
```

for each *activity* and *application* tag of `AndroidManifest.xml`. The string resource `app_name` should reside in `res/values/strings.xml`:

```
<string name="app_name">Hello world!</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually the title shown at the top of the screen is the label assigned to the Activity.

Update all your Activities label with Hello World